# NavigatetoSobject in lightning issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Can we listen to navigate to sobject event fired in the two component which is present inside container component and container component is lightning out in the visual force page.

```
<container component>
<comp1>
<comp2>
</container compoenent>
```

All three are in common aura:application
container component---lightning out--->Vf page

In Vf page I am trying to listen the event